# Scala - create seq with tuple of random numbers

Tags: scala

I would like to get something like:
`Seq((1,2), (42, 45), (54, 52), ...).`
In other words I would like to create `Seq` of length `n` with pairs of random integers.

I tried to to do something like:
`(1 to n).toSeq.map(_ -> (scala.util.random.nextInteger(),scala.util.random.nextInteger() ))`  
However, it returns some `IndexedSeq` instead of `Seq`.
Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: It isn't "instead". [IndexedSeq](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/IndexedSeq.html) is a subtype of `Seq`. It just provides the additional information that the indexed accesses are fast. If you want to erase the too exact type, you can use [type ascription](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#ascription).

Comment: Or you can put the `toSeq` after the `map`. In any case, it shouldn't matters and you shouldn't be using **Seq** anyways.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That doesn't "help": the inferred type of `.toSeq` in the end is `IndexedSeq` :) How did you mean it that one "shouldn't be using Seq anyways"?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin oh, didn't know `toSeq` wasn't returning a `Seq`, weird. - For the second point, take a look to [this](https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/2ae2570c8856037a7738#problems).

Comment: You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56147577/4993128), and its answers, informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, it is OK that it returns `IndexedSeq` because this is a subtype of `Seq`. But Scala has a library method called `fill` that will do what you want:

```
Seq.fill(n)((scala.util.Random.nextInt(), scala.util.Random.nextInt()))
```

However it is probably best to be explicit about the actual type you want (`Vector`, `List` etc.):

```
Vector.fill(n)((scala.util.Random.nextInt(), scala.util.Random.nextInt()))
```

This can still be assigned to a `Seq` but you can choose the appropriate implementation for your application.